# Finding explicit functions given implicit relationships of x(t),y(t) and t

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, parametric

I'm not sure I used the proper terminology in the title of the question, but here goes. We know that :

$$x^2+y^2=(a+b)t^2+3$$

$$x^2y^2-2=abt^4+(2a+b)t^2$$

where $a,b>0$.

How do we prove that :

$$x^2=bt^2+2$$

$$y^2=at^2+1$$

I tried solving for $x^2$ in the first equation and then plugging it into the second equation. However, that brings $y^4$ and $y^2$ terms. I tried completing the square and ended up with this huge square root looking nothing like the solutions above.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve such questions easily, it is imperative to simplify them as much as possible, for ease of solving.

We can simplify the above equations by writing them as $$x^2+y^2 = A$$ $$x^2y^2 = B$$
Then, as $y=\frac{B}{x^2}$, substituting this in the 1st equation will give us a quadratic in $x^2$. We can easily solve this by the quadratic formula, and by substituting the values of $A$ and $B$, we get the desired result.